# Datepicker plugin not working in a textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am unable to include Datepicker on a textarea. I had successfully used it in CodeIgniter but when I tried to put it in osCommerce, it's not working. I am not using any template or other addons in osCommerce.

In the below code segment I'm trying to have the Datepicker work for the textarea named `comments`:

```
<tr><td class="main" width="75%"><b><?php echo //DELIVERY_INFO;?></b></td></tr>
</table>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" >
<tr>
<td id="datepicker"><?php echo tep_draw_textarea_field('comments', 'soft', '60', '5'); ?></td>
</tr>                      
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The datepicker isn't supported with a `textarea` element, specifically it's supported with `span` and `div` elements for inline mode and only `input` elements otherwise.

[Reference](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js#L154)

Here is the recommended way to use a datepicker:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

HTML:

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text">
```